# For loop through different IDs with JS?

Tags: javascript, html, button

So I have 30 buttons (id="button1" to "button30"):

```
<button type="button" class="buttons" id="button1">1</button>
```

and I set up some JS so that the button changes colors on every click:

```
        let index = 0;
        const colors = ['green', 'red', '#405cf5'];

        let btn = document.querySelector('#button1');
        document.querySelector('#button1').addEventListener('click', function(){
            btn.style.backgroundColor = colors[index];

            index = index >= colors.length - 1 ? 0 : index + 1;
        })
```

I'm not sure how to set this up so that all my buttons do this without copy and pasting and manually typing out the ID each time.

Comment: `.querySelectorAll()` + a property they all have in common (e.g. they are buttons, the class `buttons`, the id starts with `button`, ...) + `this` and `data-*` attributes. Also you might want to have a look at the modulus operator `%`

Comment: Should every button have its own "color cycle"? So first click on `button1` -> `green`, second click on `button1` -> `red`. What will be the color of `button2` if we now click that for the first time?  `green` or `red`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delegate, please.

Here I find the closest static container of the buttons (if no container use `document`) and any click inside the container is checked against the thing we want clicked - you can test against any valid selector.

```js
let index = 0;
const colors = ['green', 'red', '#405cf5'];
document.getElementById("buttonContainer").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.matches("button.buttons")) {
    tgt.style.backgroundColor = colors[index++ % colors.length];
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="buttonContainer">
  <button type="button" class="buttons" id="button1">1</button>
  <button type="button" class="buttons" id="button2">2</button>
  <button type="button" class="buttons" id="button3">3</button>
</div>
```

If there are other buttons not to be affected we can use a class

```js
let index = 0;
const colors = ['green', 'red', '#405cf5'];
document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.matches("button.buttons")) {
    tgt.style.backgroundColor = colors[index++ % colors.length];
  }
})
```

```html
  <button type="button" class="buttons" id="button1">1</button>
  <button type="button" class="buttons" id="button2">2</button>
  <button type="button" class="buttons" id="button3">3</button>

<button class="otherbutton">Dont color me</button>
```

Comment: Why do you make the assumption that there's a "closest static container" (that's not the `document`)? Imho it's unclear if there should be one `index` for all buttons or one `index` per button.

Comment: So if none we use document. And if a color per button, OP will tell and it is trivial to change. My code is still useful and likely complete

Comment: _"if none use `document`"_ - Then this will act on every button. Might want to adjust the `.matches()` selector in that case.

Comment: I fail to understand your adversity against answers based on partial information. I have answered hundred of thousands of JS questions since 1997 and I am rarely misunderstanding or guessing poorly what the askers need